# Solving $5^n > 4,000,000$ without a calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $n$ is an integer and $5^n > 4,000,000.$ What is the least possible value of $n$? (answer: $10$)

How could I find the value of $n$ without using a calculator ?

Comment: Some people are able to multiply by 5 with pencil and paper, without a calculator.

Comment: Solve $5^k>2000$ then your $n$ must be $2k$ or $2k-1$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I could do that but I wanted to know if there was some other way of doing that

Comment: $5^3=125$, $5^4=625$, $5^5=3125$, a bit over $3000$. So $5^{10}$ should be around $10$ million, $5^9$ too small.

Comment: [I've read about this](http://downlode.org/Etext/power.html), @Gerry :) $$warning: \ \ link \ \ to \ \ text$$

Comment: @The, thanks - I was thinking of that story, but I couldn't remember the name, so didn't try to search for it.

Comment: @TheChaz: Brilliant! Truly brilliant.

Comment: You can't do log base 5 operations in your head?

Comment: @TheChaz That is one awesome story by the genius of Asimov.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
&  5^n &>& 4.000.000\\
\Leftrightarrow & 5^n &>& 5^6 \cdot 2^8 \\
\Leftrightarrow & 5^{n-6} &>& 256.\\
\end{eqnarray}
Then, $n=10$.

Comment: Fine, but how to solve $5^{n-6} > 256$ ?

Comment: @wap26 $5^3=125$, $5^4=625$, therefore $n = 4+6 = 10$

Comment: good old euler theorem

Comment: Shouldn't it be $n>10$ ?

Comment: @Sush $n$ _can_ be $\gt 10$ in addition to $10$, so shouldn't it be $n \ge 10$

Comment: @ColeJohnson, you are right!

Answer (score 44):

Divide 4000000 by 5, **without a calculator**, getting 800000. Divide again; 160000. Again; 32000. Then 6400, then 1280, then 256, then 51 (rounding), then 10, then 2. So $2\times5^9$ is about 4000000, so $5^{10}$ exceeds 4000000.

Comment: Now do it for $5^n > 6.24*10^{310}$ ;)

Comment: @Polynomial - Can you easily solve that without a calculator?  I get to `5^(n-308) > 2^312*3*13` or so and then need to estimate log(2)/log(5) part to enough precision that I can multiply by a three digit number and know I'm not off by 1 or introduce approximations 624 ~ 625.  I can sort of estimate values (e.g., Newton's method) to get within about ~1 (I find N=444 instead of 445), but would be very hard to prove.

Comment: @Polynomial, why you pickin on me? Your comment would apply just as well to any of the other answers (except the Python program). Anyway, everyone knows $624=5^4$ (roughly), and $\log_{10}5=.7$ (roughly), so $n=4+(308/.7)=444$ should be about right, close enough for government work.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The intent wasn't to pick on you, I was just joking. I actually upvoted you. The fact that you're dividing by two makes this a very good answer, because you have to take it to ridiculous extremes (like I did) before this method becomes implausible to use.

Answer (score 14):

$4,000,000 = 2^2 \times 10^6 = 2^8 \times 5^6$, so you want $5^{n-6} > 2^8 = 256$.  Well, $5^3 = 125\ldots$.

Answer (score 11):

By logarithm rules: 
$$5^{n}>4\cdot10^{6}\iff n>\log_{5}2^{2}2^{6}5^{6}=\log_{5}2^{8}+\log_{5}5^{6}=\log_{5}2^{8}+6=\log_{5}256+6$$

Since these are relatively small numbers I assume it is ok to write
: $5^{3}=125$ thus clearly $3<\log_{5}256<4$ hence the minimal $n$
that satisfies this inequality is $4+6=10$

Answer (score 8):

I dunno, this is a tough one, especially without a calculator.

Here is the Python program I used to figure this one out:

```
for n in range(1,11):
    print "5^%s-4,000,000 = %s" % (n, pow(5,n)-4000000)
```

Here is the output:

```
5^1-4,000,000 = -3999995.0
5^2-4,000,000 = -3999975.0
5^3-4,000,000 = -3999875.0
5^4-4,000,000 = -3999375.0
5^5-4,000,000 = -3996875.0
5^6-4,000,000 = -3984375.0
5^7-4,000,000 = -3921875.0
5^8-4,000,000 = -3609375.0
5^9-4,000,000 = -2046875.0
5^10-4,000,000 = 5765625.0
```

It looks like $n=10$ is the answer.

Comment: Not a tough one without a calculator, and definitely too easy with a Python Program :P

Comment: These slippery problems can sometimes turn around and bite you in the asp (that's what Cleopatra would have said).

Comment: Pretty sure a computer counts as a calculator (unless you have a Python interpreter built in your brain, if so, fair enough..)

Comment: Hmm @Thomas, don't get technical on me now :-).

Comment: You could also have done `import math; math.ceil(math.log(4000000,5))`

Comment: True, but it wouldn't have had that excitement of discovery :-).

Comment: Hmm, I'm picking up a few negative votes here.

Comment: Hmm, that's +3 -3 so far...

Comment: @copper.hat: I don't believe that the OP was looking for a brute force argument carried out by a computer. This explains at least my downvote, just in case you're seriously concerned about them.

Comment: @NilsMatthes: Thanks Nils! It was actually meant as a joke, since obviously 'without a calculator' would preclude a computer. It would only concern me if someone was upset by it...

Comment: @copper.hat: No hard feelings on my side.;) I usually don't consider jokes as helpful answers, that's all. Cheers!

Comment: People have no sense of humoUr...

Comment: @copper.hat i do.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Sabyasachi: :-)!

Answer (score 7):

It helps if you remember that $ln(2) \approx 0.7$ and $ln(10) \approx 2.3$. (These are common bases to work in, so they're generally useful numbers.)

$$\begin{align}
5^n &> 4\ 000\ 000\\
\ln(5^n) &> \ln(4\ 000\ 000)\\
n (\ln 10 - \ln 2) &> 2 \ln 2 + 6 \ln 10\\
n (2.3 - 0.7) &> 2 \times 0.7 + 6 \times 2.3\\
1.6 n &> 1.4 + 13.8\\
1.6 n &> 15.2\\
1.6 n &> 16 - 0.8\\
n &> 10 - 0.5\\
n &> 9.5\\
n &= 10
\end{align}$$

A bit much for mental arithmetic, but quite doable just typing into this here box.

Answer (score 3):

> The easiest way to multiply by $5$ without a calculator is to multiply
>   by $10$ and then divide by $2$, i.e.: $$1: 5\times 5 = 50/2 = 25$$ $$2: 250/2 = 125$$ $$3: 1250/2 = 625$$ $$4: 6250/2 = 3125\ldots$$ Won't take you very long to get to
>   $10$.

True. And for large power, use approximations :

$$5^{n} = \frac{10^n}{2^n} $$

$$5^9 = \frac{10^9}{2^9} = \frac{1,000,000,000}{512} \cong \frac{1,000,000,000}{500} \cong 2*10^6 < 4*10^6 $$

$$5^{10} = \frac{10^{10}}{2^{10}} = \frac{10,000,000,000}{1024} \cong \frac{10,000,000,000}{1000} \cong 10^7 > 4*10^6$$

It's not a mathematical way to prove, but it's a way to find the result using approximation.

Comment: *cough* typo *cough*

Comment: may you explain the comment please ? Something bad in the answer ?

Comment: @Al_th: It looks as though you are saying $10^7>4 \cdot 10^7$. Otherwise, the above comment seems unhelpful (trust me - *I would know!*)

Comment: Oww ... I wanted to state that $10^7 > 4.10^6$ ... Thanks for pointing this out ! :>

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to multiply by 5 without a calculator is to multiply by 10 and then divide by 2.  ie:  1: 5x5 = 50/2 = 25.   2: 250/2 = 125.  3: 1250/2 = 625.  4: 6250/2 = 3125...  Won't take you very long to get to 10.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_{10}(5^n)=n\cdot \log_{10}(5)\approx n\cdot 0.7$$

$$\log_{10}(4000000)=\log_{10}(4)+6\approx 6.6$$

$$7\cdot 9=63\ \text{so that }\ \boxed{n=10}\ $$

$\log_{10}(2)\approx 0.3$ was only used giving $\log_{10}(5)=\log_{10}(10)-\log_{10}(2)$ and $\log_{10}(4)=2\cdot\log_{10}(2)$

(if non integer values are allowed $n\approx \frac {6.60206}{0.69897}$)

Answer (score 1):

$5^n > 4,000,000$ find integer $n$.

- take $\log10$ of both sides
- $n\log5>2\log2+6\log10=2\log2+6$
- $n > (2\log2+6)/\log5$  (recall from log paper log2~0.3 and log5~0.7 within a few %.
- $n > 6.6/0.7$ ~ $9.4$ thus rounded up
- $n = 10$

Comment: I remember log10(2) as 0.3010 and hence log10(5) is 0.6990 so 0.3 and 0.7 are much closer than "within a few %"!

Comment: your memory has more significant figures than mine.. bravo.. I knew it was< 0.1% but close enough for government work.

Answer (score 1):

Taking square roots of both sides we solve $5^r>2000=25\cdot80$. The right side is approximated from below by $5^2\cdot5^2\cdot3$ so we want $5^{r-4}>3$ or $r=5$, so $n=2r=10$. Check $n=9$ is too small: $5^9<2^9\cdot 3^9<2^9\cdot 3^5\cdot 3^4=512\cdot 243\cdot 81<125,000\cdot 100<4,000,000$.